# R Regular Expression : extracting speaker in a script

Tags: regex, r, text-mining

I would like to use R to extract the speaker out of scripts formatted like in the following example:

"Scene 6: Second Lord: Nay, good my lord, put him to't; let him have his way. First Lord: If your lordship find him not a hilding, hold me no more in your respect. Second Lord: On my life, my lord, a bubble. BERTRAM: Do you think I am so far deceived in him? Second Lord: Believe it, my lord, in mine own direct knowledge, without any malice, but to speak of him as my kinsman, he's a most notable coward, an infinite and endless liar, an hourly promise-breaker, the owner of no one good quality worthy your lordship's entertainment."

In this example, I would like to extract: ("Second Lord", "First Lord", "Second Lord", "BERTRAM", "Second Lord"). The rule is obvious: it is the group of words situated between the end of a sentence and a semi-column.

How can I write this in R ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
library(stringr)  
body <- "Scene 6: Second Lord: Nay, good my lord, put him to't; let him have his way. First Lord: If your lordship find him not a hilding, hold me no more in your respect. Second Lord: On my life, my lord, a bubble. BERTRAM: Do you think I am so far deceived in him? Second Lord: Believe it, my lord, in mine own direct knowledge, without any malice, but to speak of him as my kinsman, he's a most notable coward, an infinite and endless liar, an hourly promise-breaker, the owner of no one good quality worthy your lordship's entertainment." 
p <- str_extract_all(body, "[:.?] [A-z ]*:")

# and get rid of extra signs
p <- str_replace_all(p[[1]], "[?:.]", "")
# strip white spaces
p <- str_trim(p)
p
"Second Lord" "First Lord"  "Second Lord" "BERTRAM"     "Second Lord"

# unique players
unique(p)
[1] "Second Lord" "First Lord"  "BERTRAM"
```

### Explanations of regex: (which are not perfect)

`str_extract_all(body, "[:.?] [A-z ]*:")` a match is started with either `:` or `.` or `?` (`[:.?]`) followed by a whitespace. Any character and whitespace is matched until the next `:`.

### Get position

You can use `str_locate_all` with the same regex:

```
str_locate_all(body, "[:.?] [A-z ]*:")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more thing: how can I get the position of the expression in the string ?

Comment: Care to explain what regex statement does?

Comment: @cafe876 I think that warrant another question. Hint: `gregexpr("Second Lord:", body)`.

Answer (score 3):

**gsubfn/strapplyc**

Try this where `x` is the input string.  Here `strapplyc` returns the portion of the match within parentheses:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(x, "[.?:] *([^:]+):", simplify = c)
[1] "Second Lord" "First Lord"  "Second Lord" "BERTRAM"     "Second Lord"
```

**gregexpr**

Here is a second method.  It uses no external packages. Here we calculate the starting and ending positions (`start.pos` and `end.pos`) and then extract out the strings they define:

```
> pos <- gregexpr("[.?:] [^:]+:", x)[[1]]
> start.pos <- pos + 2
> end.pos <- start.pos + attr(pos, "match.length") - 4
> substring(x, start.pos, end.pos)
[1] "Second Lord" "First Lord"  "Second Lord" "BERTRAM"     "Second Lord"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding these two approaches! Very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At least in this case, a better solution is to search the text in a more structured form.  Mining structured documents is almost always easier than unstructured ones.  Since the source is Shakespeare, there are many copies floating around the internet.

```
script_url <- "http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=allswell&Act=3&Scene=6&Scope=scene"
doc <- htmlParse(script_url)
character_links <- xpathApply(doc, '//li[@class="playtext"]/strong/a')
characters <- unique(sapply(character_links, xmlValue))
#[1] "Second Lord" "First Lord"  "Bertram"     "Parolles"
```

Note that the version of the text you use makes a big difference.  Open Source Shakespeare is very good in that the html pages are well structured and include classes.  On the other hand Bartleby pages are not.  Let's run the analysis again:

```
script_url2 <- "http://www.bartleby.com/70/2236.html"
doc2 <- htmlParse(script_url2)
tbl <- xpathApply(doc2, '//table[@width="100%"]')[[1]]
italics <- xpathApply(tbl, '//tr/td/i')
characters2 <- unique(sapply(italics, xmlValue))
#[1] "First Lord." "Sec. Lord."  "Ber."        "Par."        "hic jacet."  "Exit."      
#[7] "Ber"         "Exeunt."
```

In this case you can't programmatically tell the difference between characters, stage directions (without compiling a list of possible stage directions and ignoring them), and emphasised speech.  Choose your text source wisely!